# php website not showing correctly in utf-8

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding

I have a website which has some non standard characters such as `ë`, `Ç` etc.

The website uses ISO-8859-1 as it's character encoding, however at this point I want to switch it to UTF-8 for some reasons related to rss feeds.

When i change the character encoding to utf-8 the mentioned characters are displayed incorrectly.

I set the charset through the php header function:

`header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");`

Any idea as to how to fix this problem ?

Comment: Can you give a link if the page is online?

Comment: How did you change the character encoding?

Comment: Using header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8");

Comment: @Aldo: That does only change how the data is interpreted but not the data itself. It’s like translating a text from language A to language B by just writing “This text is written in language B” above it.

Comment: Which kind of data isn't put out correctly. Each static text or just data from a database? Have you changed the encoding of your PHP files to UTF-8 as well?

Comment: Actually the data being output incorrectly was some data i retreived from another website in forms of rss feeds

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never heard about entities ?
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_XML_and_HTML_character_entity_references .

Else, you have to reencode your files (with your editor, you should be able to save your files specifying an encoding).

You can also do it with external programs, like iconv

```
iconv -f ISO-8859-1 -t utf8 your_file > your_new_file
```

Comment: Thanks I downloaded some utility to reencode my files to utf-8 and it worked.

Comment: -1 for your advice to use entities but +1 for the right hint to reconvert the files ;)

Comment: Seconding @Kau-Boy. Entities are antiquated for anything but escaping HTML meta characters like `&amp;`.

Answer (score 1):

```
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```

So, are you using ISO-8859-1 or UTF-8? This header is telling the browser "please assume the content of this site is encoded in ISO-8859-1 and interpret it as such." If the content of the site is *not* actually in this encoding, the result will be gibberish to some extend.

This goes to say that the problem is that what it says on the label is not actually what's in the can.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing that information in the database, check the database collation, it must be UTF-8 also.